# Campo com # não aparece no Mysql por _GET

Tags: mysql

Bom pessoal, não sei onde posto a pergunta..

Desculpe-me se estiver em área errada!

Bom, eu estou quebrando a cabeça com um código na minha pagina.
O código funciona ele envia os dados para o meu banco de dados, só que não está mandando um pedaço do campo por ter esse character " # " ai só está mandando metade.

Olhem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está chegando o resultado só que não chega o final do código nick=Teste"**#6287**"

Olhem o resultado no banco de dados:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do Arquivo processar.php

```
<?php
$conexao = mysqli_connect("phpmyadmin", "user", "pass");
mysqli_select_db($conexao, "db");


     $novoemail = addslashes($_GET["novoemail"]);
     $nick = addslashes($_GET["nick"]);

       $inserir = "INSERT INTO ajuda (id, email, usuario) VALUES (NULL, '$novoemail', '$nick');";
        mysqli_query($conexao, $inserir) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
        echo"";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você pode estar fazendo é separar o campo de envio :

> meusite/ir/processar.php?novoemail=Testando@mailnesia.com&nick=Teste&num=6287

E depois "juntar" os dois no PHP:

```
$nick = addslashes($_GET['nick'] . "#" . $_GET['num']);
```

Comment: Mas ai eu teria que criar uma outra variável para pegar o numero? 
Porque eu já tenho uma variável que pega o nome#numero junto..

Comment: sim, as âncoras não são enviadas do navegador para o servidor.

Comment: você está pegando por input essas informações?

Comment: Sim estou..
<span class="lien-blanc-gras">Teste#6287</span>

Comment: var nick = document.getElementsByClassName("lien-blanc-gras")[0].textContent;

Comment: faz 2 <span>, um para o nick e outro para o numero

Comment: A pagina não é minha da onde tou puxando os dados então não tem como eu fazer.

Comment: então o jeito é manipular o texto que você quer, alterando o valor da string para envio e depois alterar novamente o valor: --JS-- var exemplo = "Teste#1234"; var resultado = exemplo.replace("#", "."); alert(resultado);  --PHP-- $nick = addslashes($_GET['nick']); $nickCorrigido = str_replace('.', '#', $nick); echo $nickCorrigido;

Comment: Consegui amigo obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Você terá que codificar ele, porque o `#` direto é reconhecido pelo navegador com "URL dinamica" que é usado para principalmente interagir no front-end, com HTML, CSS e JavaScript, inclusive fiz uma resposta sobre o assunto:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/235335/3635

Tendo entendido o porque isto falha agora vamos ao passo de corrigir, para que funcione você terá que codificar (trocar no caso) o `#` para `%23`, ou seja vai ficar assim:

```
processar.php?novoemail=Testando@mailnesia.com&nick=teste%236287
```

Mas fique tranquilo, quando usar `$_GET['nick']` vai retornar `teste#6287` perfeitamente.

Se o link for gerado pelo seu script então para facilitar pode usar `urlencode()`, **mais ou menos** assim:

```
<?php
$email = urlencode('Testando@mailnesia.com');
$nick = urlencode('teste#6287');

echo '<a href="processar.php?novoemail=' . $email . '&nick=' . $nick . '">Link</a>';
?>
```

Outra coisa, **NÃO USE `addslashes` para escapar em mysqli**, esta função pode até funcionar aparentemente, mas não tem este propósito, ainda mais dependendo de codecs (variações de utf8, latin1, etc) por ai, então dependendo do codecs talvez algum caractere poderá ocasionar erro de sintaxe, então não faça isso:

```
 $novoemail = addslashes($_GET["novoemail"]);
 $nick = addslashes($_GET["nick"]);
```

O ideal é usar a função própria para isto, `mysqli_real_escape_string`, assim:

```
 $novoemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_GET["novoemail"]);
 $nick = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_GET["nick"]);
```